# Maven: Custom external jar as a dependency for a microservice architecture

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices

I am trying to create a microservices java project with springboot.
My idea is to create a separate maven project which will contain all DTOs and utils classes common to all microservices.
(I know many will criticize this choice but that's how I decided to proceed at the moment).

So I created the *lib* project and the *base* project. Working on the base project, my IDE can correctly read the classes contained in the *lib* module.
During the compilation phase, i make a clean install of the *lib* project and then a clean install of the *base* project: at this point I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: interface slt.mytest.base.services.TestsService
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/mytest/slt-base-be/src/main/java/slt/mytest/base/services/impl/TestsServiceImpl.java:[8,47] package slt.mytest.libs.entities.base does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/mytest/slt-base-be/src/main/java/slt/mytest/base/services/impl/TestsServiceImpl.java:[9,45] package slt.mytest.libs.models.base does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/mytest/slt-base-be/src/main/java/slt/mytest/base/repositories/TestsRepository.java:[5,47] package slt.mytest.libs.entities.base does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/mytest/slt-base-be/src/main/java/slt/mytest/base/repositories/TestsRepository.java:[10,60] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class TestEntity
```

How can I make the *lib* a base project visible?
Is there a way to automatically start compiling libs on every base install?

in general ... how would you manage this case?

Thanks

***lib project pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>slt.mytest</groupId>
    <artifactId>libs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>libs</name>
    <description>Libs Module of mytest</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.22</org.projectlombok.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

***base project pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>slt.mytest</groupId>
    <artifactId>base</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>base</name>
    <description>Base Module of mytest</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.22</org.projectlombok.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>slt.mytest</groupId>
            <artifactId>libs</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: If you want to create lib which is a good idea don't make it being packaged by spring-boot-maven-plugin because it will produce a jar which can not being consumed by others...

Comment: Create a seperate maven project and add dto and other utility inside it. Add spring boot starter as dependency but not as parent in your lib. Import and in your client create config class where you will import the packages of spring boot you want to include. Take a look at @import in spring boot. Lib will be added as a jar so make sure it compiles independent

Comment: It is a standard practice and @khmarbaise is right

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You may need to install your `lib` project to your local repository (`.m2/repository`). You can do this by executing `mvn install` (or use your IDE's GUI features) in the `lib` project. If `base` still does not compile, execute `mvn dependency:resolve` on `base`.

Your IDE may identify the dependency, and that is why there are no errors in your code editor, but Maven will not unless it can resolve the dependency. It will try to resolve from your local repository and remote repositories (which, in your case, since you have not defined any in your POM, is just Maven Central).

Comment: Hi Oliver, I'm already performing a mvn clean install in the libs project before compiling the base project. It did 't work unfortunally

Comment: Did you check your local repository to ensure the jars were placed?

Comment: Yes, i confirm that my libs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is in my .m2 directory

Comment: Try it without the -SNAPSHOT bit, both in the lib and the client project

Comment: @user3187960 Did this help?